# Countdown in Django Html Template

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to implement a countdown, that will give me the number of days and hours until the deadline.
I have tried two different methods using the html filter but nothing is displayed. Is the filter not already part of Django?

**models.py**

```
class Quote(models.Model):
   deadline = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
```

**html filter**

**Method 1:**

```
{{ quote.deadline|timeuntil:today }}
```

**Method 2:**

```
{{ quote.deadline|timesince:comment_date }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use `timesince` without argument ?

```
{{ quote.deadline|timesince }}
```

https://moonbooks.org/Articles/How-to-get-the-time-difference-from-now-in-a-Django-template-/